# Multiple Perl packages in one file?

Tags: perl, module, package, perl-module

Please enumerate all reasons supporting the following saying: "Each Perl package should be placed into a separate file (no several packages in one file)".

For example, I have a code like this:

```
{
package Classes::City;
# ...
}
{
package Classes::Cities; # for lists of multiple cities
# ...
}
```

Should I refactor this code into two separate `.pm` files? (Consider this question as an example of the above question, not as an additional opinion-based question. I want just the list arguments, not an opinion-based answer.)

Comment: Where did you get your quote? Please add a source. That might already point you to the explanation. I right now can think of several, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @simbabque I don't remember where I got the quote

Comment: Please don't accept my answer just yet. That discourages other answers and there will likely be someone who has more time and does more research to give a better one than mine.

Comment: Don't change it for the sake of changing it, but yes, using separate .pm files avoids a couple of issues.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is that Perl loads modules for you automatically when you `use` or `require` them with package names. It does so by converting the package name to path in your file system and checking each of your `@INC` directories for that file.

```
use Classes::City;
# will be converted to on Linux:
Classes/City.pm
```

If you have both Classes::City and Classes::Cities in one file, you cannot load ::Cities without loading City because the file Classes/Cities.pm does not exist anywhere in your `@INC`.

```
use Classes::City
# blows up
```

You now need to keep track which packages are in what file. That makes your life harder.

Comment: It makes your users' lives harder, too. What if your user gets a warning in a `Classes::Cities` subroutine and wants to look at the source code?

Answer (score 0):

A single answer is that this is not the intended usage model, and the compiler/interpreter will fight with you in ways that aren't always obvious.

Your example is very similar to something I try to do: create a class, and then a container class for the original class within the same file.

I've found that 8 times out of 10, I can get it to work without too much pain.

If the original class contains BEGIN blocks for (say) accessors, it's not always clear that they get executed before you try to use the accessors in your container class.  I'm sure there are combinations of gyrations which will make this happen, but at that point, it seems cleaner to just use the 1 package/file model.

Even forcing a `BEGIN { import class;}` from within the container class won't always be enough to get things to run in the necessary order.

Comment: I recognize that the question was "list all reasons", and this is only one.